# PyDev Python simple hello world program keeps terminating without returning anything to the console

Tags: eclipse, python-3.x, pydev

I am trying to set up Python 3.6 using the PyDev plugin in Eclipse oxygen for JS and Web Development. I'm trying simply print hello world to the console and it just terminates after a few seconds no errors are returned thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide the code you're using?

Comment: print("Hello World") simple as that... I downloaded the current version of PyDev n

Comment: Since you don't say exactly what you did, one can only simply refer you to these instructions: http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_install.html